# Python Method Signatures

Tags: python, methods, python-3.4, method-signature

When I use the `help` function on a builtin magic method, there is often a `/` in the function signature.

```
>>> help(int.__add__)
Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__add__(self, value, /)
    Return self+value.
```

However, when I apply the `help` function to a either a standard builtin method, or a user-defined magic method, there is no `/` in the function signature.

```
>>> help(list.append)
Help on method_descriptor:

append(...)
    L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end

>>> class c:
        def __add__(self, other): return 1

>>> help(c.__add__)
Help on function __add__ in module __main__:

__add__(self, other)
```

What does the `/` in the method signature indicate?